# Is it correct to use "uppercased"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, is-it-a-word

Is **uppercase** a valid verb?
Could I say for example "you should use your password uppercased"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a verb in any common dictionary, nor generally accepted.

Use the following instead:

> You should use an upper-case password.

Comment: Agreed; it's not common or generally accepted. Then again, you can verb almost anything and still be readily understood. :) (That particular example isn't optimal to demostrate this, as it only makes the phrase clumsier. But consider e.g. "change your password to uppercase" vs "uppercase your password".)

Comment: @Jonik: Yeah. There's lots of made-up verbs you can get-away with simply because humans aren't picky with language, though what's the point if you're not even making things shorter/clearer (probably the opposite here)?

Comment: The Merriam-Webster dictionary seems to have it, going by the other answer.

Comment: Ok, that surprises me. Put it this was, you'd get strange looks if you used it in speech here (Britain). Also, using it as a gerund just makes it more awkward.

Comment: To me *Use an upper-case password* means something very different from *Use your password upper-cased*: the former means "choose a password with only upper-case letters", whereas the latter is "use your password, but convert all the letters to upper case".

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, it is acceptable to some people:

[Merriam Webster: Uppercased](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uppercased)

Comment: "First known use: 1949", so it predates personal computers.